# Jquery Auto Calculation

Tags: jquery, html

Credits to the owner of the code.

How can I make the script into `multiplication`? the script an `addition` of `.amount`. Please help.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-right amount" >
  </td> 
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-right amount">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-right" id="total_amount" readonly>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
  $(function() {

      $('.amount').mask('#,###.##',{reverse : true});

      var total_amount = function() {
          var sum=0;
          $('.amount').each(function(){
              var num = $(this).val().replace(',','');

              if(num != 0) {
                  sum +=parseFloat(num);
              }    
          });
          $('#total_amount').val(sum.toFixed(2));
      }
       $('.amount').keyup(function(){
          total_amount();
       });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Will you always have only 2 amount fields?

Comment: yes, i need the two fields bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity element (or neutral element) of Multiplication operation in Real numbers is one. So your `var sum = 1;` will be that.

After each iteration, in your case two hardcoded, you will multiply sum with new number. Hence changing `sum *=parseFloat(num)`.

That leaves you with the old regular multiplication.

```js
  $(function() {

      $('.amount').mask('#,###.##',{reverse : true});

      var total_amount = function() {
          var sum=1;
          $('.amount').each(function(){
              var num = $(this).val().replace(',','');

              if(num != 0) {
                  sum *=parseFloat(num);
              }    
          });
          $('#total_amount').val(sum.toFixed(2));
      }
       $('.amount').keyup(function(){
          total_amount();
       });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-right amount" >
  </td> 
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-right amount">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-right" id="total_amount" readonly>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hey @M1K10, can I ask you another question?

Comment: Yes, just create new Question.

Comment: @M1K10 bro, how about if I want to use division and subtraction operation, what will be the script look like?, thank you for responding.

Comment: Substraction is inverse to addition, so just change + to -.

Comment: Division is inverse to multiplication so just change * to /.

Comment: @M1K10 bro, do i still need to change `var sum=`?